# Prevent event capturing after first event

Tags: javascript, css-transitions, transition

I have a code: https://jsfiddle.net/AleshaOleg/zj69u8Lz

```js
document.querySelector('.js-delete').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  event(e, trigger);
});

function event(e, callback) {
  e.target.addEventListener('transitionend', function(e) {
    e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
    callback(e);
  });
}

function trigger(e) {
  alert("DONE");
}
```

```css
.js-delete {
  -webkit-transition: width .3s;
  transition: width .3s;
  width: 100px;
}

.js-delete:hover {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button class="js-delete">Delete</button>
```

Where, I have event listener on click, and after this click one more event inside, which triggers after transition is ends, and alert message should be visible.

Everything, is ok. But the question is, when i click more than 1 time, before transition ended, I will have same number of alert messages.

So, I want to get, just one alert independently, how many time I click to my button.

Thanks!

Comment: why are you registering 'transitioned' eventListener?

Comment: @otherstark in `event` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use `arguments.callee`, it's deprecated (will not work with 'strict mode').

Just use named functions for event handlers instead of anonymous and it will be easier to remove them.

Also some wrapper function to add the event handlers again.

```js
// Start application lifecycle by registering click event
registerClickHandler();

function registerClickHandler() {
  document.querySelector('.js-delete').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
}

function clickHandler(e) {
  // Immediatley remove click event handler after event fired
  e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, clickHandler);
  // Register transition event handler
  registerTransitionHandler(e);
}

function registerTransitionHandler(e) {
  e.target.addEventListener('transitionend', transitionHandler);
}

function transitionHandler(e) {
  // Immediately remove transitionend event handler after event fired
  e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, transitionHandler);
  // Register click event again
  registerClickHandler();
  // Run callback at transitionend event
  transitionEndCallback(e);
}

function transitionEndCallback(e) {
  alert("DONE");
}
```

```css
.js-delete {
  -webkit-transition: width .3s;
  transition: width .3s;
  width: 100px;
}
.js-delete:hover {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button class="js-delete">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a hack to me but I added a variable `busy` that I toggle so it won't be called if it's been called already

```js
var busy=false;

document.querySelector('.js-delete').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 if(!busy){
  busy=true;
  event(e, trigger);
  }
});

function event(e, callback) {
  e.target.addEventListener('transitionend', function(e) {
    e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
    callback(e);
  });
}

function trigger(e) {
  alert("DONE");
  busy=false;
}
```

```css
.js-delete {
  -webkit-transition: width .3s;
  transition: width .3s;
  width: 100px;
}

.js-delete:hover {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="js-delete">Delete</button>
```

Comment: it's ok, but so 'dirty' solution - in my opinion:)

Comment: I concur it's 'dirty' but it's what came to mind first

Comment: yeah, the idea to make a 'flag' the easiest one

Comment: take a look @ my answer for the clean way to do this

Answer (score 0):

You're adding multiple event listeners to `transitionend` every time you click the delete button.  I've tweaked your code so see if this works:

```
var clickHandler = function(e) {
    event(e, trigger);
}

document.querySelector('.js-delete').addEventListener('click',clickHandler);

function event(e, callback) {
  e.target.addEventListener('transitionend', function(e) {
      e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
      callback(e);
   });
}

function trigger(e) {
   alert("DONE");
   e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, clickHandler);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this is happening because each time you click the button, you are registering a new eventListener with 'transitionend' ... tbh, I''m not sure why you have this anyway. Modify your code to this:

```
function event(e, callback) {
    e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
    callback(e);
}
```

Comment: but, i want to save `transitionend` event

Comment: save it? what for?

Comment: ok, task from practical point of view: http://aleshaoleg.github.io/zeoalliance.

Same effect, after we click a lot of times 'uninstall' button.

Comment: ya, if you modify your script to what I provided, it works identically to this - it works just as you have it, minus it not showing "DONE" over and over. Still not really understanding what you mean by "saving" it. and side note... each time you click "Popup" and cancel, you have to click back in the browser that many times to get back :)

Comment: I'm not sure, what you understand the idea clearly. Under 'save' - i mean, make this works, so `addEventListener('transitionend')` must be in my code.
try to click, 'uninstall' button inside popup three times in row, before transition ends. And you will see, three alert messages, but I want to see just one alert.